# Blackberry SecurityException : This token was registered by a different module and therefore the operation is not allowed

Tags: cordova, blackberry, ota

When I install app via `OTA` it work correct, but when I install app with `Standard` installation method, I get `SecurityException` after application start:

```
guid:0xBEF92E11214401C3 time: Sat Dec 15 13:25:08 2012  severity:0 type:2 app:UI data:GS+Q2 b0ad4b69net.rim.device.apps.internal.security.SecurityApp$SecurityStatusScreen
guid:0xF010BD043A6522FA time: Sat Dec 15 13:25:08 2012  severity:0 type:2 app:SecurityApp data:ASta
guid:0xF010BD043A6522FA time: Sat Dec 15 13:25:08 2012  severity:0 type:2 app:SecurityApp data:SPNR
guid:0xD4741B512180F81B time: Sat Dec 15 13:25:08 2012  severity:0 type:2 app:net.rim.ribbon.coverage data:Invoke = signalLevel-89
guid:0x9C3CD62E3320B498 time: Sat Dec 15 13:25:08 2012  severity:1 type:3 app:Java Exception data:
    SecurityException
    This token was registered by a different module and therefore the operation is not allowed.
    net_rim_bb_unifiedsearch_lib-5(505BDB70)
     UnifiedSearchServicesImpl
     removeAllData
     0x9467
    net_rim_bb_toolkit-3(505BDB84)
     ToolkitSearchableImpl
     powerUp
     0x619C
    net_rim_cldc-30(505BD476)
     Events
     dispatchSystemEvent
     0x1301
    net_rim_cldc-10(505BD476)
     Application
     doProcessNextMessage
     0x2D58
    net_rim_cldc-10(505BD476)
     Application
     processNextMessage
     0x2272
    net_rim_cldc-10(505BD476)
     Application
     enterEventDispatcher
     0x218E
    net_rim_services_impl(505BD583)
     ServiceStartup
     tier0
     0x5D52
    net_rim_services_impl(505BD583)
     ServiceStartup
     main
     0x5C74
```

What cause of this problem?

Comment: Never saw this before. Did you edit jad file before OTA download? The issue looks related to universal search but this is really black box, at least I don't know how it assigns key values from app translation to the application itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually problem occurred because my tester used `jad` file from `OTAInstall` folder instead using `clx` from `StandartInstall` folder